# Host Runtime of Azure Function App is not available for a long period of time

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm running a App on Azure with a Static Web App as frontend and a Function App as backend. Currently I'm experiencing some issues with the Function App. It is unavailable from time to time. When diagnosing the issue I can see that there was an exception after which the host runtime was unavailable for a longer time:
[image]

After some time the Function App recovers and everything again works as expected. This happens somewhat frequently. Any help figuring out the root cause is appreciated.

Comment: any solution for this issue?